# Why is Typescript trying to read files in `./build` as input files?

Tags: typescript

I've been knocking my head against the wall for an hour over this.

I have `outDir` and `rootDir`, set.  `include` only has `src`, TS only lists files in `src` via `showConfig`, yet it's trying to compile 4 (out of 26...) files in `build` for some reason.

Just hoping another pair of eyes will help:

```sh
➜ git:(main) ✗ yarn tsc
error TS5055: Cannot write file './build/err/critical.d.ts' because it would overwrite input file.
error TS5055: Cannot write file './build/err/err.d.ts' because it would overwrite input file.
error TS5055: Cannot write file './build/err/index.d.ts' because it would overwrite input file.
error TS5055: Cannot write file './build/err/levels.d.ts' because it would overwrite input file.

Found 4 errors.

➜ git:(main) ✗ yarn tsc --showConfig
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": [
            "esnext"
        ],
        "module": "node12",
        "target": "es2021",
        "strict": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node12",
        "noEmit": false,
        "outDir": "./build",
        "rootDir": "./src"
    },
    "files": [
        "./src/array-async.ts",
        "./src/array.ts",
        "./src/async-event-emitter.ts",
        "./src/console.ts",
        "./src/gen-await.ts",
        "./src/is-object.ts",
        "./src/object.ts",
        "./src/string.ts",
        "./src/err/critical.ts",
        "./src/err/err.ts",
        "./src/err/index.ts",
        "./src/err/levels.ts",
        "./src/err/validation.ts"
    ],
    "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "**/__tests__/**/*",
        "build/**/*"
    ],
    "compileOnSave": true
}
```

Comment: @jonrsharpe - It's saying that those 4 files are being used as inputs.  And it doesn't have any problem with the other files in `build`, only these 4 for some reason.

Comment: Does the [`explainFiles`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#explainFiles) config or (`--explainFiles` CLI flag) tell you anything useful?

Comment: @JeffBowman - What a handy debugging tool, I didn't know about that, so thanks!  Unfortunately not though.  The only reference to `critical`, for instance, in the output is to `src/err/critical.ts` and it looks perfectly valid (that it's importing and being imported).  No references to `build` anywhere.

Comment: It looks like you might be falling into the case described in [microsoft/TypeScript#16749](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16749) and particularly [microsoft/TypeScript#35541](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35541). (Unfortunately I didn't see a workaround in those, but it's a starting point.)

Comment: @JeffBowman -- #35541 at least is the same issue, but I figured it out.  It is indeed because I was importing a file from `build`, in my case because I had an import (presumably a VSCode auto-import) referencing the package name that I was in.  In #35541 it's because he's referencing the root dir of the package, so basically the same thing.  No idea why `--explainFiles` doesn't show that.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question in case anyone comes across this.

I had, in my project, one import statement written like:

```
import { whatever } from 'this-package'
```

instead of a relative import (`from './file'`)

meaning that a file from `build` was indeed being used as an input.  I only wish the error message were clearer about that.